# Difference between $p\left(x\right)\cdot{q\left(x\right)}$ and $\left(p\cdot{q}\right)\left(x\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, notation

Let $p\left(x\right),q\left(x\right)\in{R\left[x\right]}$ such that $p\left(x\right)=x$ and $q\left(x\right)=x+a$.

My lecture notes state that "$p\left(x\right)\cdot{q\left(x\right)}=x^2+xa$ and $\left(p\cdot{q}\right)\left(x\right)=x^2+ax$ are different if $R$ is not commutative."

I was wondering why $p\left(x\right)\cdot{q\left(x\right)}$ and $\left(p\cdot{q}\right)\left(x\right)$ are different (I see that $xa\neq{ax}$) because some books write that $\left(p\cdot{q}\right)\left(x\right)=p\left(x\right)q\left(x\right)$.

Which one must we use in the ring of polynoms?

Comment: To be honest, I find this strange. Is it not the case that $(p\cdot q)(x)$ is precisely defined to be $p(x)q(x)$?

Comment: I personally think that here we are actually evaluating the polynoms at an $x$ in the ring R. The first case I wrote is the product of the evaluation in $x$, while the second case is the evaluation in $x$ of the product. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the variable in a polynomial ring commutes with everything. This is needed to simplify a product of polynomials down to a polynomial again. To use your example: If you multiply $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ and don’t assume commutativity, you get
$$
  p(x) \cdot q(x) = x (x + a) = x^2 + x a.
$$
To turn this into the standard form of a polynomial, you have to swap $a$ and $x$ at the end, i.e. $x$ should commute with $a$. We call the resulting polynomial (i.e. what you get after swapping $x$ and $a$ in the example) $p \cdot q$.

Now, an important feature of polynomials is that you can replace the variable $x$ by an element $z$ of the ring (or even an element of an $R$-algebra). If $z$ commutes with everything (as is would in the more familiar case of commutative rings), swapping the order is justified for $z$ as well and “evaluating at $z$” becomes a ring homomorphism $R[x] \to R$. If it does not, however, $(p \cdot q)(z)$ is different from $p(z) \cdot q(z)$. This means that the polynomial ring is a lot less nice in the non-commutative setting.

---

Having written this, is occurs to me that I find the statement in your lecture notes confusing as well, because $p(x) q(x)$ should be equal to $(pq)(x)$ *if $x$ is the variable of the polynomial ring* (which it appears to be) by definition of multiplication. What really should be stated is that $p(z) q(z)$ is not necessarily equal to $(p q)(z)$ if $z$ is some other value and $p(z)$ denotes evaluation of $p$ at $z$.